# how do I get datatable value from vertical to horizontal?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I want to put my value like:

result | one | two | three

average | 1.4 | 2.45 | 3

But my result turned out to be like:

result | one | two | three

average | 1.4

average | 2.45

average | 3

is there a way to change it? my codes are below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dtGrid = gridData.DataSource as DataTable;
        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
        Math columnIndex = new Math();

        dtResult.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(string));
        dtResult.Columns.Add("One", typeof(double));
        dtResult.Columns.Add("Two", typeof(double));
        dtResult.Columns.Add("Three", typeof(double));
        dtResult.Columns.Add("Four", typeof(double));
        dtResult.Columns.Add("Five", typeof(double));
        dtResult.Columns.Add("Six", typeof(double));

            for (int i = 1; i < dtGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                List<double> avgList = new List<double>();

                for (int j = 1; j < dtGrid.Rows.Count ; j++)
                {
                    avgList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dtGrid.Rows[j][i].ToString()));

                }
            double averageList = columnIndex.getAverageValue(avgList);

            dtResult.Rows.Add("average", averageList);

            gridData2.DataSource = dtResult;
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a new row in each iteration of the inner loop(each columns), That is why you are getting unexpected result; So what you have to do is, Create a new row before starting iteration and add avg of each column to the newly created row.add the new row to the column after the column iteration completed; You can Change the logic of Adding items to the list like this:

```
   DataRow dAvgRow = dtResult.NewRow();
        DataRow dMinRow = dtResult.NewRow();
        dAvgRow[0]="average";
        dMinRow[0] = "Minimum";
        for (int i = 1; i < dtGrid.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            List<double> avgList = new List<double>();
            for (int j = 1; j < dtGrid.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                avgList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(dtGrid.Rows[j][i].ToString()));
            }
            double averageList = avgList.Average();
            dAvgRow[i] = averageList.ToString("#.##");     
            dMinRow[i]=avgList.Min();
        }
        dtResult.Rows.Add(dAvgRow);
        dtResult.Rows.Add(dMinRow); 
  gridData2.DataSource = dtResult;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I used your code, but it gives an ArgumentException saying "This line already belongs to the current table" -->  dtResult.Rows.Add(dRow); here 
 sorry I'm new to c# I don't know what to do..

Comment: The code works fine for me, make sure that `dtResult.Rows.Add(dRow);`  is outside the loop; or else please update the question with new code

Comment: @un-lucky OP has `double` type for columns, but in your code it is `String`. That might be causing the issue.

Comment: @HariPrasad : Thanks for the value point. @Leo; i have updated the answer

Comment: ah.. I forgot to put } after ("#.##").. now it works find!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Great solution (+1).

Comment: Quick question, if I want to find min, max, etc. do I keep on adding DataRow dRow1 = dtResult.NewRow();  dRow[0]="Minimum";
DataRow dRow2 = dtResult.NewRow();  dRow[0]="Maximum"; and add  dtResult.Rows.Add(dRow1);?? 
or is there other simply way to do this??

Comment: @Leo : Yes absolutely, I have updated the answer with a row `Minimum`

Comment: @un-lucky Thank you!!